# How make examplary, full module step by step?

Tags: magento2, module

I searched how make examplary, full  module for Magento 2 step by step. Can You send me honest links?

Comment: There isn't a full module. Each module has different features and elements, there's no standard.

Answer (score 0):

here is link for [you](https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/how-to-create-a-magento-2-module-393)

and here is ready-made module example [demo](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento225-demo/tree/master/app/code/Srtpl)

you can get reference from there.

Answer (score 0):

To create module in magento 2,you can refer below link where step by step explanation to creating module.

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-modules/